# function not working when put inside Vue methods

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js

I have a function that goes to my api file get a list of users from /users that is loaded through springboot from my database.

```
 created() {
            api.getUsers().then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                this.retrievedUser = response.data;
                this.showRetrievedUser = true
            })
        }
```

The above gets all the data and displays it within table, however if I put it into methods{} it doesn't work.

```
  methods: {
            created() {
                api.getUsers().then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                    this.retrievedUser = response.data;
                    this.showRetrievedUser = true
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

What exactly is the reason for this? I've looked at other examples that do very similar thing to what I'm doing, and they're calling the functions within method field.

Comment: What error is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created()` is the life cycle event that will be called in the component creation process. You can visit [here](https://dzone.com/articles/vuejs-series-lifecycle-hooks#:%7E:text=Lifecycle%20hooks%20are%20the%20defined,diagram%20indicating%20the%20hook%20sequence.) for more info on vue life cycle

methods is the component property where we can add the user-defined methods or any click event methods.

In your case, you can update your logic as below

```
created() {
            this.getData();
        } 

methods: {
            getData: function() {
            // you can also pass parameters as getData: function(param1, param2)
                api.getUsers().then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                    this.retrievedUser = response.data;
                    this.showRetrievedUser = true
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot for the link. I now understand what was going on.

Comment: we are here you help you always. glad you found the solution @KrystianKan

Answer (score 1):

Well `created()` is a Vue's lifecycle method, so I guess it's reserved, try to rename your method, that is:

```js
methods: {
  fetchUsers () {}
}
```